a surjective homomorphism from a quotient ring to the initial ring
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$, let $I$ be a proper ideal of $R$. If $\varphi:R/I\to R$ is a surjective ring homomorphism, is it necessary that $I$ must be the zero ideal?

No, consider the ring $C([-1,1])$ of continuous functions on $[-1,1]$ and let $I = \{f \in C([-1,1]) : f([-1, 0]) = 0\}$ be the ideal of functions that vanish on the first half. Then the quotient $C([-1,1])/I$ is isomorphic to $C([-1,0])$, which is clearly isomorphic to the original ring.

Please notice that pure problem-statement questions should not be answered. Instead we should encourage the OP to improve them. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards. This also applies to duplicates and I am pretty sure that this is one.
